# Inno Setup Pascal Script to search for running process

Tags: windows, inno-setup, pascalscript, tasklist

I am currently trying to do a validation at the uninstall moment. In a Pascal script function, in Inno Setup, I want to search for a specific processes, with a wild card if possible. Then, loop through all find results, get the Image Name and Image Path Name, in order to check if the program that is about to be uninstalled is the same as the one running.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an exemplary task for WMI and its WQL language. Getting list of running processes through WMI is even *more reliable* than Windows API. The below example shows how to query the [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx) class with the [`LIKE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) operator:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
```

```pascal
[Code]
type
  TProcessEntry = record
    PID: DWORD;
    Name: string;
    Description: string;
    ExecutablePath: string;
  end;
  TProcessEntryList = array of TProcessEntry;

function GetProcessList(const Filter: string;
  out List: TProcessEntryList): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
  WQLQuery: string;
  WbemLocator: Variant;
  WbemServices: Variant;
  WbemObject: Variant;
  WbemObjectSet: Variant;
begin
  Result := 0;

  WbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  WbemServices := WbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2');

  WQLQuery :=
    'SELECT ' +
    'ProcessId, ' + 
    'Name, ' + 
    'Description, ' + 
    'ExecutablePath ' +
    'FROM Win32_Process ' +
    'WHERE ' +
    'Name LIKE "%'+ Filter +'%"';

  WbemObjectSet := WbemServices.ExecQuery(WQLQuery);
  if not VarIsNull(WbemObjectSet) and (WbemObjectSet.Count > 0) then
  begin
    Result := WbemObjectSet.Count;
    SetArrayLength(List, WbemObjectSet.Count);
    for I := 0 to WbemObjectSet.Count - 1 do
    begin
      WbemObject := WbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(I);
      if not VarIsNull(WbemObject) then
      begin
        List[I].PID := WbemObject.ProcessId;
        List[I].Name := WbemObject.Name;
        List[I].Description := WbemObject.Description;
        List[I].ExecutablePath := WbemObject.ExecutablePath;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  S: string;
  I: Integer;
  Filter: string;
  ProcessList: TProcessEntryList;
begin
  MsgBox('Now we try to list processes containing "sv" in their names...',
    mbInformation, MB_OK);

  Filter := 'sv';
  if GetProcessList(Filter, ProcessList) > 0 then
    for I := 0 to High(ProcessList) do
    begin
      S := Format(
        'PID: %d' + #13#10 +
        'Name: %s' + #13#10 +
        'Description: %s' + #13#10 +
        'ExecutablePath: %s', [
        ProcessList[I].PID,
        ProcessList[I].Name,
        ProcessList[I].Description,
        ProcessList[I].ExecutablePath]);
      MsgBox(S, mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: That works really well. The only thing is that I get the Executable path in the following format: "PROGRA~1\243~1.106\prog.exe". Can I do something to have the full path, like displayed in the task manager, instead of the compact path with the ~1 ? Strangely, for the second folder, the ~1 is in the middle of the folder name, probably because of the dots in the name...

Comment: That looks like a 8.3 filename. Try to call the [`ExpandFileName`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_expandfilename.htm) function to expand it to full path.

Comment: It did not work, but no worries, I found a way that worked for me (it's a bit more complex though). http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=GetLongPathName_()
Thank you for your great help :)

Comment: You're welcome! Hm, the `ExpandFileName` function internally calls `GetFullPathName` rather than `GetLongPathName`. It makes me wonder [`what's the difference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#short_vs._long_names) between them...

Comment: I think this only works in `Unicode Inno Setup`.  I use the non-Unicode version and this will compile for me but always errors out.  I think `Unicode Inno Setup` has more support for Variant casting etc...  This place I get stuck at on this script is where `WbemObjectSet.Count` gets used first.

Answer (score 1):

If not work.Please change as follows.

(old)
for I := 0 to High(ProcessList) do

(new)
for I := 0 to (GetArrayLength(ProcessList) - 1) do